# Navigation Drawer clickable area

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I have found a strange behavior on the clickable area for opening the Navigation Drawer:

[image: Navigation drawer clickable area to open it]

Android 4.2.2+

- The application icon and the action bar title are clickable (see red box on the image)

Android 4.2.2-

- Only the application icon is clickable (see yellow box on the image)

Any workaround for this? I would like the Android 4.2.2- would have a bigger clickable area.

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason this occurs is due to the way the [`ActionBarView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L196) inflates the home layout. Starting in Jelly Bean mr2, they added a layout called [`action_bar_up_container`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_up_container.xml), which is added as a parent to the `ActionBar` home layout when it's first inflated. Before this; however, the [`action_bar_title_item`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_title_item.xml) wasn't added to the `action_bar_up_container` because it didn't exist and although contains a background, is only [enabled and clickable when `ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled` is set to `false`.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarView.java#L786)

So, you could enable the title container and make it clickable like this:

```
    final int abUp = getResources().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");
    final View titleContainer = (View) findViewById(abUp).getParent();
    titleContainer.setEnabled(true);
    titleContainer.setClickable(true);
```

But because of the way each `View` is inflated before Jelly Bean mr2, the up container and title container wouldn't be linked, so to speak.

[image: Example]

So, it seems like the only workaround would be to attach a `View.OnTouchLIstener` to the `titleContainer` and implement some sort of pseudo-selection on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, which seems like more trouble than its worth to me, but if there's a better solution I welcome it.

Although, I suppose you could also call `ActionBar.setCustomView` and inflate a layout that mimics the home and title containers. This would probably be the easiest workaround.

Comment: I am going to try that! Thank you

Comment: I have tried to get the "titleContainer" but I get a null pointer exception on Android 2.3:

Comment: @user2729171 The `ActionBar` first appeared in 3.0.